# An array is given and it can be of four types:

Tags: arrays, algorithm

An array is given and it can be of four types :

1. increasing
2. decreasing
3. first increasing then decreasing
4. first decreasing then increasing

Without traversing the array we need to tell its type.

Example:

a. increasing. eg 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

b. decreasing. eg 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

c. incr-decr. eg 1 2 3 4 9 8 7 6 5

d. decr-inc. eg 9 8 7 6 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: I don't know your question

Comment: how many elements in the array (min) and how many get operations can you perform on the array

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question, except possibly for lack of code, but then again it asks for an algorithm.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what about "This question does not show any research effort"?

Comment: the question is unclear.

Comment: @Henry - how could you say no research. it could have multiple answers. also  part c and part d are difficult ones for which i am not confident.

Answer (score 6):

First, for the third and fourth cases, there must be at least three array elements in order to have an increase followed by a decrease, or vice-versa.

Assuming three or more elements, you can answer the question by doing the following two checks:

- compare the first and second element        (Comparison 1)
- compare the second to last and last element (Comparison 2)

Here is a table showing how the results of these two comparisons can be used to determine the array type:

```
Comparison 1 | Comparison 2 | Type
     <       |       <      | increasing
     >       |       >      | decreasing
     <       |       >      | increasing then decreasing
     >       |       <      | decreasing then increasing
```